# Creating high quality images for printing (CMYK) on websdrver

Tags: php, node.js, linux, cmyk

I'm struggling with generating high-quality images for printing - mainly because there is really poor support for CMYK colors in PHP libraries and Linux CLI tools.

The situation is as follows. I have input materials in tiff format and CMYK colors - it is the background. I need to add some text to it and save as tiff with CMYK colors. The challenge is to use exact CMYK colors (so no temporary export/import to sRGB during the process is possible).

My first thought was to use Imagemagick but Imageimagick has no option to draw in CMYK. I need to work in sRGB and export material to CMYK. So some information about colors are changed during the process.

It seems this is not possible with PHP to add text to image without temporarily converting colors to sRGB, so I'm looking for any option like Linux CLI tool, node.js lib, etc. The goal is to at least generate text as an image with a transparent background and with colors defined in CMYK with exact values or do the same directly on the background image.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickpixel.setcolor.php), some parts of Imagick appear to support CMYK at least, but I can’t say for certain how much.

Comment: You are right but unfortunately, you can't "draw" using CMYK - only sRGB is supported while "drawing text".

Comment: I don’t have a computer in front of me, so what happens when you set a CMYK color and then call a text function (is it `annotation`?). Does it convert to RGB automatically or does it throw?

Comment: Color seems to be inverted ie $fillColor->setColor('cmyk(0%,0%,0%,100%'); produce white text. 100% Magenta produces vivid green etc.

Comment: Okay. I apologize, but I just have to ask, are you viewing the image in a CMYK-aware manner? Photoshop or a [browser that supports it](https://chromachecker.com/info/en/page/webbrowser)?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes I think so. I work on Linux but chrome should display good colors for jpg image, and I still see inverted colors. Nevertheless I found lots of information about bugs while drawing in CMYK. I think that ImageMagic doesn't support CMYK while drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I gave up with Imagemagick. As we can use PDF for professional printing I decided to go this way.

I installed TCPDF and TCPDI. With TCPDI I imported previously prepared pdf template with graphics etc. Using TCPDF I added necessary dynamic text - TCPDF support CMYK with no issues.

Depending on where you print you can embed fonts to PDF (it can be done with TCPDF) or change texts to outlines which is a small challenge. I needed to change fonts to outlines (client request) so I did it with Ghostscript.

It took me a whole day to figure it out, so I post it in case somebody will have a similar problem. Definitely not an answer to the question, but at least a good solution for the problem itself.

Comment: I’ve spent a long time in PDF and CMYK land, so I know your pains. Glad you found a solution!